# Importing a dataframe to another script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a scripts (script 1) in python that produce a `dataframe` like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]), index=('27-04-2020','28-04-2020'), columns=('Prediction', 'Certainty'))
```

I want to import the `dataframe` into (script A). However, I can not seem to find a way for importing dataframes.
Can someone help me with a solution for this?

Comment: Don't think of it as 'importing the dataframe' from this script. Think of how you would get any variable from this script into your other scripts. In this example, df is just a variable that you want to use somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this in script_a.py as

```
from script_1 import df
```

But a cleaner way to do that would be:
In script_1.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_dataframe():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]), index=('27-04-2020','28-04-2020'), columns=('Prediction', 'Certainty'))
```

In script_a.py

```
from script_1 import get_dataframe
df = get_dataframe()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I have implemented your code in both my own script and the tried replicating the example, however both dataframes comes out as "NonType"?

Answer (score 1):

@user2077935 has the right start.

You just need to add a return statement.

So script_1.py

```
def get_dataframe():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]), index=('27-04-2020','28-04-2020'), columns=('Prediction', 'Certainty'))
    return df
```

The rest stays the same